# Equation and Function concept

Tags: functions

Is it true that the linear concept has different meaning when applied to equations and to functions?

Everyone calls the "$y = ax + b$" a linear equation even though the function $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ $f(x)=y=ax+b$ is not a linear function.

Should we think that the term "Linear" when applied to "equations" means that the solutions $(x,y)$ to the equation represents points $(x,y)$ that form a straight-line whereas the term "Linear" when applied to functions means that the mapping holds the superposition property ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. There are two common concepts that share the name linear. There are linear transformations, from linear algebra, which are functions between vector spaces that satisfy the conditions in the Wikipedia article you linked to. Then there are polynomials of the form $ax + b$, which are usually called linear polynomials, although when viewed as a function (on a field, say) they are not 
linear transformations.

As you said, graphing the function $x \mapsto ax + b$ (as a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$), we get a straight line, so it makes sense to call it linear. Typically, though, a function from a vector space to another one that is of the form $x \mapsto Ax + b$, where $A$ is some linear transformation and $b$ is a vector, is called an affine transformation.

Comment: See if i make sense.We have the first order polynomial ( ax + b ).By treating it like a function y=p(x) = ax + b, even tho p is not linear, it's graph resemble a line. Hence, as x-> ax+b yields the graph of a line we call the polynomial, a linear polynomial.A linear equation is made , then ,of equating the linear polynomial to some variable y ?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds right.

Comment: Ben, help me decipher this.We can make the linear equation look like Ax + By = c   right ? That would result in f(x,y) = c right ? That would result in f(x,0) + f(0,y) = c where both "f(x,0)" and "f(0,y)" would be linear subfunctions for x and for y, respectively.So, can i say a linear equation comes from equating the sum of a linear function to x and a linear function to y to some constant ?

Comment: I would say that in general, a linear polynomial in $n$ variables $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ is one of the form $a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + \dots + a_nx_n + b$ for constants $a_1, \dots a_n, b$. Then a linear equation is something that comes from setting some linear polynomial to be zero.

Comment: Hmm i know but i still have a bad time calling a polynomial linear when the polynomial function is not linear and the only polynomial who resembles a line is the first order polynomial.Can we think of each nth order polynomial a1x1+a2x2+⋯+anxn+b = 0  as f(x1,x2,...,xn) = -b ? In that case we would be creating a linear equation by equating a linear function with respect to all variables to some constant b ( which could be 0 or not, meaning we would have a line/plane/etc passing through the origin )

Comment: I know what a linear FUNCTION is but i'm trying to understand what a linear EQUATION is.The equation could even be an Ordinary Differential Equation whose solution doesn't describe necessarily a line.There are some Ordinary Differential Equation that are called linear and some that don't.Should we really come up with some concept of a linear equation describing a line to check if the Ordinary Differential equation ( just another kind of equation ) is linear ?

Comment: Yes, you can think of it as an equation $f(x_1, \dots, x_n) = -b$ where $f$ is a linear function. The Wikipedia article on linear equations might be helpful. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation. I think usually when you talk about a linear ODE, it's one where linear combinations of solutions will still be solutions (i.e. the set of solutions forms a vector space). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation

Comment: But the only linear ODE whose linear combinations of solutions wil stil be solutions is the linear homogeneous ODE.The linear non-homogeneous ODE doesn't hold the property.